# Render partial views from ruby gems

Tags: rubygems

I have created a ruby gem, that contains some views and functions. Lets call it **example-gem**.

I have a ruby on rails project, called **Produn**. With some views inside **Produn**, i will render like this:

```
= render 'templates/content/ed/email'
```

the full path for that file is app/views/template/content/ed/email.html.haml.

Can i render views from **example-gem** in **Produn**? And how?
Thank you for your responses.

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course you can, for this you need to use [Rails Engine](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html)

1) create file with name engine.rb in lib/gem_name directory

```
    module MyGem
      class Engine < Rails::Engine; end
    end
```

2) require engine in lib/gem_name.rb

```
    require 'gem_name/engine'
```

3) after that you can render template/partials from your gem's app/views directory

```
 = render 'templates/content/ed/email'
```

requiring rails engine in gem work for me, you can check my gem [server_side_validation](https://github.com/GaneshNavale/server_side_validation)

Answer (score -2):

use it, i think this is helpful for you.

```
render :partial => 'my_gem/my_partial'
```

Comment: Which Error is  came? Nguyễn Hà Nhân

Comment: Missing partial templates/content/ed/email with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :slim, :haml]}